# Does the Night Mode of the screen display (LCD) save more energy?

Tags: energy, condensed-matter, material-science, popular-science, liquid-crystal

In some cases, we can enable the Night Mode (reversing the bright and dark color of the display; such as White Text, Black Background) for the screen display.

[LCD(Liquid-crystal display)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display) seems to be a common monitor display devise nowadays, so let us consider the LCD at this moment.

> (1) Will the Night Mode save more energy?
>
> (2) How can we evaluate the energy efficiency ratio between, for example **the Day Mode and the Night Mode**?
>
> (3) A bonus question: whether the energy efficiency (of Day Mode and Night Mode) varies for [CRT(Cathode ray tube), LCD, Plasma, and OLED(organic light-emitting diode)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_CRT,_LCD,_Plasma,_and_OLED)?

[image]

Comment: Related on [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4373/does-a-webpage-with-a-black-background-save-energy), [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30541/lcd-led-panel-power-consumption), Superuser [1](http://superuser.com/questions/497507/lcd-led-screens-how-color-affects-the-power-consumption), [2](http://superuser.com/questions/115647/does-it-save-battery-to-have-your-desktop-background-set-on-a-dark-color), and [3](http://superuser.com/questions/135445/is-there-considerable-energy-saving-using-a-black-background-on-my-website).

Comment: Also [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38140/does-a-black-screen-save-battery-on-an-iphone-4). (Most of these are LED/LCD/OLED)

Comment: That said, I'm not too sure this is off-topic for us. A general, qualitative question about how devices work (not how to build them, not how to program them, not what studies have been done on them) seems okay.

Answer (score 5):

An LCD panel has a background illumination which is always on if the panel is on and uses the same amount of energy regardless of what is displayed. The only way you can save energy is by dimming the panel which will dim the background illumination but not by displaying something black. The night mode is (today) primarily intended to go easy on your eyes.

For a CRT display, the story is different. There the cathode ray sweep the screen very fast, modulating its intensity to match the desired brightness. Displaying something black will save energy. That's also why CRT give blacker blacks. What you see is really no light, not just light absorbed by the liquid crystal matrix.

I should mention however that as a general rule, CRTs use way more energy than LCDs.

I'm not sure about plasma and/or OLED displays. Maybe somebody else can shed light on this (no pun intended).

Comment: thanks Jonas, +1. If LCD with dim background is designed to be the black background, I suppose this can save amount of energy? (I am hinting that way may be the environmental-friendly way to go.)

Comment: I would say that the display uses more energy, as the crystal is normal non-blocking, and current is needed to make it black.

Answer (score 0):

Oled uses less energy in night mode since your screen is being lot per pixel if it is old, the black pixels use no light

Comment: The second half of your sentence is a little less than clear. Could you add more to this answer?